# Let $\,f \colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\ge \frac12 |x-y|$

Tags: real-analysis

I am stuck on the following problem that says:

> Let $\,f \colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function such that $\,|f(x)-f(y)|\ge \frac12 |x-y|, \forall x,y \in \Bbb R$ . Then which of the following options is **correct**?
>
> 1. $f$ is both one-to-one  and onto
> 2. $f$ is one-to-one  but may not be onto
> 3. $f$ is onto but may not be one-to-one
> 4. $f$ is neither one-to-one nor onto

I do not know how to approach this particular problem even though I know about one-to-one and onto functions. Can someone explain? Thanks and regards to all.

Comment: the condition rules out a function which is not 1-1, since if $x \ne y$ then $\mid x-y \mid \gt 0$, but if $f(x)=f(y)$ then $f(x)-f(y)=0$

Comment: The given inequality says that for $x \neq y$, we have $f(x) \neq f(y)$, so the function must be 1-to-1.

Comment: you can then see the function must be strictly monotone. so if it is not onto, it must be bounded above or below. how does the condition relate to this?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/601587/6179

Answer (score 4):

Another idea for the onto part. You can see immediately that $f$ is one to one (injective). You know that a continuous function which is injective is monotone. Suppose that the function is not onto. Then one of the limits $\lim_{x \to \pm\infty} f(x)$ exists and is finite.

Suppose that $L=\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)$ is finite (the same argument works if the other limit is finite). Then take $y$ arbitrary and $x \to \infty$ in the initial inequality and you'll get $|L-f(y)| \geq \infty$, contradiction.

---

Or you could work directly in the initial inequality. Fix $x_0 \in \Bbb{R}$ and let $y$ go to $\pm\infty$. Then $|f(y)-f(x_0)|$ goes to $+\infty$. This implies that both the limits in $\pm \infty$ are infinite, and the monotonicity implies that their sign is different. By the intermediate value theorem we conclude that the image of $f$ is $\Bbb{R}$ so $f$ is onto.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose on the contrary, that $f$ is not one-to-one. Then there are two distinct $x$ and $y$ for which $f(x) = f(y)$, which is impossible given that $f(x) - f(y) \neq 0$.

Suppose $f$ is not onto. By continuity, it is either bounded above or below, and by the previous result it's either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing. Suppose it's increasing and bounded above, take a $x_0$ such that $f(x_0) > \sup_x f(x) - \delta$, then $f(x_0 + 2\delta) > \sup_x f(x)$ which is absurd.

Comment: I am having trouble to understand the last line "then $f(x_0 + 2\delta) > \sup_x f(x)$ which is absurd. " Otherwise,the rest of the explanation is fine .Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: $f(x_0)>\sup_xf(x)$ is what the last line says. In other words, there is a point in the domain of $f$, $x_0$, for which $f(x_0)$ is strictly greater than the supremum of $f$. This is impossible.

Comment: We assume that $f$ is increasing (otherwise reverse signs, it doesn't really matter), so $f(x_0+2\delta)-f(x_0) = |f(x_0+2\delta)-f(x_0)| ≥ \frac12|(x_0+2\delta)-x_0| = \delta$, so $f(x_0+2\delta) ≥ f(x_0)+\delta$, but we assumed that $f(x_0) + \delta > \sup_x f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is $\DeclareMathOperator{\Ima}{Im}$ injective. Suppose $f(x) = f(y).$

$$0 = |f(x) - f(y)| \ge \frac12 |x - y| \implies x = y$$

We shall show that $f$ is also surjective.

Since $f$ is a continuous injection, it follows that $f$ is strictly monotonic. WLOG suppose that $f$ is strictly increasing.

Let $c = f(0)$ and let $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Let's show that $y \in \Ima f$.

If $y > c$, then $x_0 = 2(y - c) > 0$ so $f(0) \le f(x_0)$. We have:

$$f(x_0) - f(0) = |f(x_0) - f(0)| \ge \frac12 |x_0 - 0| = y - c$$

Hence $f(x_0) \ge y$ so $y \in \langle f(0), f(x_0)]$. Since $f$ is continuous, there exists a value $x_1 \in \langle 0, x_0]$ such that $f(x_1) = y$.

If $y < c$, then $x_0 = 2(y-c) < 0$ so $f(0) \ge f(x_0)$. We have:

$$f(0) - f(x_0) = |f(0) - f(x_0)| \ge \frac12 |0 -x_0| = c - y$$

Hence $f(x_0) \le y$ so $y \in [f(x_0), f(0)\rangle$. Since $f$ is continuous, there exists a value $x_2 \in \langle x_0, 0]$ such that $f(x_2) = y$.

If $y = c$, then $y = f(0)$.

In either case, $y \in \Ima f$.

We conclude that $f$ is surjective.